# Comment flag declined, but comment removed. Why?

Tags: discussion, flagging

This happened to me several times on this SE, even though I don't raise many flags: I raise a comment flag, it gets declined, but the comment is removed (at about the same time the flag got declined). The last time it happened [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/166233/show-flags) (link for mods only). Why? I don't mean to be overly scrupulous but I am getting concerned I'll end up with a flag ban at some point.

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/147247 on main meta

Comment: As for getting flag banned, I think only declined post flags (as opposed to comment flags) contribute to that. [Disputed flags don't count toward the ban either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243685).

Comment: They do it to me too, but I don't think it's always honest coincidence. There are absolutely no checks on how mods moderate comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers from the comment section:

> - I believe you'll find your answer [meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/147247](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/147247) on main meta – [Kate Gregory](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory) [Jun 15 at 18:31](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/comment-flag-declined-but-comment-removed-why#comment16027_7022)
> - As for getting flag banned, I think only declined post flags (as opposed to comment flags) contribute to that. [Disputed flags don't count toward the ban either](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243685). – [JJJ](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11883/jjj) [Jun 17 at 16:46](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/comment-flag-declined-but-comment-removed-why#comment16028_7022)